# Is there any way to factor out "const" field initializers in C++

Tags: c++

In C++ I have a class with some const fields:

```
class Obj {
   static const AType defaultAType; 
   const AType &cRef;
public: 
   Obj() : cRef(defaultAType) { ... }
   Obj(AType &aType) : cRef(aType) { ... }
};
```

This is a simple example.  But a real one might have many fields, and several different constructor overloads.  References and "const" fields can't be initialized in the body of a constructor or in a method called by the constructor to the best of my knowledge.  But it is a pain in the butt to synchronously maintain a number of initializers in lets say 5 separate constructor overloads.  Is there any way to properly factor out these initializers (other than a macro) ??

Comment: Sounds like you could use a [delegating constructor](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#delegating-ctor). It's hard to suggest any thing concrete without seeing more of your real code.

Comment: Yes that is the *structure* however const items, references, and class items *can't* be initialized in the body of constructors or in a non-contructor method.  Apparently the only way is in the "pre '{' initializers of a constructor  ie:  Obj : field(value) {}.  It seems there is no way to factor this type of initialization out.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by having the const and reference initializers "factored out"?  What kinds of things are you wanting to do in the bodies of the constructors that you can't do in the member initialization list?

Comment: Ok I have a class with 5 const objects in it and a few references.
They are initialized in different ways in a few different overloaded constructors.  Some of the constructors take classes as an argument from which the values to initialize the references and constant values are extracted.   The "common" factored out initializer would take all the values as arguments or a subset or one of several object references from which it extracts the values.

Comment: I would want to call that "common" method from the different overloaded variants of the constructor.- Or from a specific after construction "initializer" method.

Unlike some other languages C++ one constructor can't realistically call another constructor ( except via placement operator new which does way more than desired )  and a const or reference field can only be initialized ONCE and these can only be initialized in the "after colon before body" section of a constructor.

Comment: This simply might not be possible in the C++ languange but figured I'd ask in case there is something I missed :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a comment, you said,

> Yes that is the structure however const items, references, and class items can't be initialized in the body of constructors or in a non-constructor method.

A [delegating constructor](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#delegating-ctor) can be used to initialize reference member variables.

Expanding your example code a bit, I can see something like:

```
class Obj {
   static const AType defaultAType; 
   const AType &aRef;
   static const BType defaultBType; 
   const BType &bRef;
public: 

   // Delegate with default values for both references
   Obj() : Obj(defaultAType, defaultBType) {}

   // Delegate with default value for the B reference
   Obj(AType &aType) : Obj(aType, defaultBType) {}

   // Delegate with default value for the A reference
   Obj(BType &bType) : Obj(defaultAType, bType) {}

   // A constructor that has all the arguments.
   Obj(AType& aType, BType& bType) : aRef(aType), bRef(bType) {}
};
```

Comment: Looks like this is it,  One CAN call one constructor on the same class from another.  For some reason I missed it. :)

Comment: @peterk, glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 0):

So this is a restriction that you can't initialize const variables other than in the constructor so there is one approach in my mind. You can have one overloaded constructor with all the possible variable types as arguments and the last argument being the integer that represent which argument to take care off assuming you are considering one variable at each overload. So you can do something like this. Hope this one helps. You can increase on the number of variables to initialize.

Please note to just pass null to the references not in consideration.

```js
class Obj {
  const typea var1;
  const typeb var2;
  const typec var3;
  const typed var4;

  public Obj(typea * ptr1, typeb * ptr2, typec * ptr3, typed * ptr4, int index) {

    switch (index) {

      case 1:
        var1 = * ptr1;
        break;
      case 2:
        var2 = * ptr2;
        break;
      case 3:
        var3 = * ptr3;
        break;
      case 4:
        var4 = * ptr4;
        break;
    }

  }

}
```

Comment: doesn't do it as you can't call this overload from other constructors unless it is on a base superclass.

Answer (score 0):

No. Unless you are using C++11, where you can initialize some of them in class definition:

```
struct B
{
    B(int) {}
    constexpr B(double) {}
};

class A
{
    const B b1 = 1;
    static constexpr B b2 = 2.0;
};
```

For const values constructed from constructor input parameters, you need to use [initializer list](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list).